# Restore std.out after redirecting it

Tags: python, ipython

At some point in my code I redirect the stdout to a file:

```
sys.stdout = open(os.path.join(folder, file_env), 'w')
```

Later on, I would like to go back to the usual IPython console ( I am using Anaconda on linux)

However, if I do

```
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

the console output is displayed in the shell were spyder was started from and not in the iPython console as desired.
What is the right way to redirecting it to IPython console instead?

Comment: What does this have to do with ksh? (How does ksh knowledge help someone answer this question?)

Comment: You are right I have removed the ksh tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IPython; `sys.stdout` is **not** `sys.__stdout__`

When you assign a value to `sys.stdout` always save the previous version:

```
oldstd = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = whatever
... your code. 
sys.stdout = oldstd
```

Or better, make it context manager.